# Query with crosstab with String in double quotes ("")

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, charts

I am trying to run my report with VBA rowsource using a query.

I have a problem replacing the inbuilt access query to VBA because of double quotes.

I have tried replacing the double quotes with & CHR(34) but unsuccessful.

```
TRANSFORM Count(History_query.WAS) AS CountOfWAS
SELECT History_query.Datum
FROM History_query
WHERE (((History_query.Datum) Between [Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Text72] And [Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Text81]) AND ((History_query.WAS)=[Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Combo186]))
GROUP BY History_query.Datum
PIVOT History_query.Status In ("erledigt","offen","in Bearbeitung","abgearbeitet / beobachten");
```

above query works perfect in Access datasheet view und report chart is also generated.

I want to transform this query in VBA.

Comment: What do you mean by "run with VBA"? Are you trying to open the results of the query into a recordset?

Comment: Did you try escaping the double quotes? `sql = "TRANSFORM [...] PIVOT History_query.Status In (""erledigt"",""offen"",""in Bearbeitung"",""abgearbeitet / beobachten"");"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *single quotes*:

```
PIVOT History_query.Status In ('erledigt','offen','in Bearbeitung','abgearbeitet / beobachten');
```

Comment: the easyiest way is what the @gustav suggested. single quotes works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are running into issues escaping the quotes in vba. You would need to double up the double quotes to escape them. If you could post any errors you are getting that would be helpful. The below will get your query results into a recordset.

```
Sub run()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database: Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Recordset

strSQL = "TRANSFORM Count(History_query.WAS) AS CountOfWAS " & _
         "SELECT History_query.Datum " & _
         "FROM History_query " & _
         "WHERE (((History_query.Datum) Between [Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Text72] And [Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Text81]) " & _
         "AND ((History_query.WAS)=[Forms]![fr_M-Shiftreport]![Combo186])) " & _
         "GROUP BY History_query.Datum " & _
         "PIVOT History_query.Status In (""erledigt"",""offen"",""in Bearbeitung"",""abgearbeitet / beobachten"");"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'do vba stuff...

EXIT_PROC:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```